# Titanium - Upload iOS App on Apple App store

Tags: ios, titanium

I have developed an iOS app in Titanium Studio (`SDK 2.1.3.GA`). Now, I want to publish on the Apple App store.

I tried, but it gave me the error `add armv6`. I added it in the file `info.plist`, but still I am getting that error.

Could any one give me step by step guide to upload an iOS app from Titanium to the Apple App store?

Also, how can I set the app icon for both iPhone and iPad in Titanium?

Comment: what is your target 4.3 or greater ?

Comment: then set the armv 6 in the xcode project settings

Comment: i already do that.. but still get error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I had the same problem I did the following step after banging my head for 5 hours.

1. Start the project in simulator it will create the build folder within your project/
2. Go to the build folder->iphone, find the xcode project.
3. Open up this project in xcode. Select the main project and goto info tab.
4. Set the minimum ios development target to 5.0 (you can also select 4.3 but don't select 4)
5. Go to the build Settings tab. Remove all the architectures.
6. Now add two targets one by one. 1. armv6 2. armv7
7. Repeat this step in Valid architectures in build settings and select appropriate distribution provisioning profile.
8. Now clean the project. build archive and enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official doc of Titanium, very clear for the distribution steps.
[Distribution iOS apps](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Distributing_iOS_apps)